# Merge [polp] and [least-privilege]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

These two tags looks like duplicates to me:

1. [least-privilege](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/least-privilege): 3 questions, no wiki
2. [polp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polp): 1 question, good wiki

I think the general rule is to avoid abbreviations in tag names unless they are more established than the full name (e.g. [http](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/http)). I guess the simplest things to do would be to copy paste the tag wiki from #2 to #1, and retag the single question. Or what do you think?

Comment: Fully agree. Depending on how common the acronym is, it might make sense to make [tag:PoLP] a synonym?

Comment: @RoryAlsop Thanks for fixing it! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“POLP” is not a common abbreviation in my experience. I didn't recognize it in your question before I saw the expansion, whereas I'm familiar with the concept under its full name. So I don't see the value of keeping the synonym around. That one question (which had [an even worse tag](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/181216/revisions)) should just be retagged.

Also, since [the tag length limit has been raised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490), [principle-of-least-privilege](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/principle-of-least-privilege) now fits. So I propose to rename the tag [least-privilege](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/least-privilege) to the full name.

Comment: I agree, and have made this change, but kept least-privilege as a synonym of the full name